# Display Suite custom function field not firing

Tags: 7, display-suite

I need to add a Display Suite function field to a node.  I set up my hook, and my field shows up and I can add it to my content type in display.  However, the function isn't getting called, and it looks like it should.  I stripped my code down so I can debug this.  My custom function is in my .module file.

```
function MYMODULE_ds_fields_info($entity_type)
{

    if ($entity_type != 'node')
        return;

    $fields = array();


    $fields['splittitle'] = array(
        'title' => t('Split product title'),
        'field_type' => DS_FIELD_TYPE_FUNCTION,
        'function' => 'MYMODULE_ds_field_splittitle'
    );


    return array('node' => $fields);

}


function MYMODULE_ds_field_splittitle($field)
{

    return 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that worked for me... My Module name is drup_custom

```
function drup_custom_ds_fields_info($entity_type)
{
    if ($entity_type != 'node') {
        return;
    }

    $fields = array();


    $fields['test_title'] = array(
        'title' => t('Split product title'),
        'field_type' => DS_FIELD_TYPE_FUNCTION,
        'function' => 'drup_custom_ds_field_splittitle'
    );


    return array('node' => $fields);

}

function drup_custom_ds_field_splittitle($field)
{
  return 'My Content';
}
```

Steps to follow to see results..

- Cleared Caches
- Enabled Layout in Content Type Settings

[image]

- Now, you can see your field in disabled list

[image]

- Assign the field to which ever region you would like, Save Settings

[image]

- I can see the field content in Node View Page

[image]

Comment: Even though this was exactly what I was doing, I must not have been clearing my cache (even though I am certain I did).  Anyway, it works. Thanks!